# Project Reference in RDLC ReportViewer Report

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a Visual Studio 2005 solution which contains two projects - a Windows Forms project in VB and a class library in C#.  My VB project includes an RDLC report file.

I have recently learned that you can add custom code and external references to an RDLC report. I would like to reference my C# class library from the RDLC file (which, as I said, is in my VB project). But when you click the "..." button on the *Report -> Properties -> References* tab, it doesn't give you the option to add project references, only .NET assemblies and other .dll files on your machine.

**What is the best way to add a project reference to an RDLC?**

I tried adding my C# library .dll from both the VB and C# project bin folders, but got compile errors indicating that it could not be found. I found the workaround that instructed me to put the .dll in my Visual Studio/..../PrivateAssemblies folder. Doing this got rid of the File Not Found error, but I still got an error telling me that the class I was attempting to reference on the *Report -> Properties -> References* tab under *Classes* could not be found.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering if you ever found a solution to this issue? I am getting the same thing.

Comment: I'm curious about the best practices for this issue (hence the bounty to bump the question). Essentially I have this inherited mess of a system that I'm attempting to clean up. Part of this process includes bringing some sanity to the build/deploy process. Long story short, I'm currently in a position where I have one class library project (which gets grafted onto a SharePoint instance during deployment) with RDLC files, and another project (via a project reference) with code used by the RDLCs. What is the best practice for referencing that code? Moving it to the same project is an option.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a similar procedure for using custom assemblies or embedded code as in Reporting Services ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769 ) It sounds so lazy but my answer is to follow what Microsoft does for reporting server.